# Rename files by removing part of their existing basename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have a folder where all my multipass 3d renders are going. I had to start and stop the renders several times which lead to name changes.

names:

```
Mask_Opening_Scene_Multipass_i1_0230.exr
Mask_Opening_Scene_Multipass_i1_0231.exr
Mask_Opening_Scene_Multipass_i1_0232.exr
```

The bulk of the files are named:

```
Mask_Opening_Scene_Multipass0230.exr
```

So what I need, is to remove the, `_i1_`

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off

set list="*_il_*"

echo List of files
echo.
echo.

for /r %%a in (%list%) do (

 set file=%%a
 echo "!file!" "!File:_i1_=!")

)

pause
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Are you sure that the current directory is what you expect? Perhaps `echo %%a` within the loop.

Comment: you list files `*_iL_*`, but then try to replace `_i1_`. Is that a typo or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "list=*_il_*"

echo List of files
echo.
echo.

for /f %%a in (%list%) do (

 set file=%%a
 echo "!file!" "%File:_i1_=%")

pause
```

or

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "list=*_il_*"

echo List of files
echo.
echo.

for /f %%a in (%list%) do (

 set file=%%a
 echo "!file!" "!File:_i1_=!")

pause
```

First, you don't have the delayed expansion enabled, so you cant use the variables with "!".
Then, you use /r instead of /f, /r is for paths, /f is for files, so probably is catch a error using /r.
You don't have to especify whats the `_i1_` gonna be, you can only put `%file:_i1_=%`, will make the name disapear, and i think that the delayed var (!) is not necessary for the variables...

I hope i helped you.